# If I have estimated set of values, how to get the mean?

Tags: mean

I am a beginner in stats and need to get this clear please.

I have estimated set of values and need to calculate the mean. Do I still need to divide over N or the sum of all estimated values will be my mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear. The general method for calculating a [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean):

$ \bar{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} $

So yes, if you want to calculate the mean, you need to divide by the total amounts of elements. That is simply the definition of a mean.

Your question might also be:

*I have several means and I would like to calculate the mean out of these several means.*

Then I propose the following method to avoid skewed weighing-schemes:

$ \bar{x} = \frac{\bar{x_1} \cdot N_1 + \bar{x_2} \cdot N_2 + \cdots + \bar{x_n} \cdot N_n}{N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n} $ **(correct)**, where $N_i$ is the number of elements used in calculating mean $\bar{x_i}$ (for $i=1,...,n$).

The following would be wrong in that case: $ \bar{x} = \frac{\bar{x_1} + \bar{x_2} + \cdots + \bar{x_n}}{n} $ **(not correct)**

If that does not answer your question, then please rephrase your question.

Comment: Dear Jean, Thanks a lot for this. I understand from you that we always have to divide by population size.

Comment: @salzburg: yes, exactly.

Comment: @salzburg: Consider accepting my answer if you think it answered your question (by pressing the green 'accept' sign).